# Is Reactive Stream message or event driven?

Tags: reactive-programming, reactive-streams

I'm trying to figure out if Reactive Streams are message-driven or event-driven.
There are different version, on manifesto they say that Reactive Streams is Message Driven. But in another article they only say about Events.
Or maybe this is both this are messages that can contains events??

Answer (score 0):

With Reactive Streams, you may build Message driven or Event driven systems. The difference between Messages and Events is in the domain of the problem, or the characteristics of the source. While two processes exchange Messages, a process monitoring sensors consumes sensor Events. The mouse may be a sensor for  mouse clicks, the system bus may be a partner for message exchange. Reactive Streams do not specify particular kinds of sources or sinks; it establishes a universal contract for sources and sinks to attain certain objetives. It doesn't matter if the thing being streamed ir a message or an event.